# Slide transition error in lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

I can't get these images to work correctly when the lightbox is pulled up. It's like I'm getting multiple incorrect edits on the Jquery the second you switch images.

I've setup two of the images over on this Pen: http://codepen.io/nathan-anderson/pen/jqJyNy This is all I'm doing to call the plugin

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------//
//---------------// Calling Hideseek Live Search //---------------//
//----------------------------------------------------------------//
    $('#lightgallery').lightGallery({
        download: false,
        counter: false,
        zoom: false,
        thumbnail: false,
        mode: 'lg-fade'
    });
```

As you can see, it loads them but puts them in halfs for some reason.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [Codepen Updated](http://codepen.io/Rubio/pen/mPoRpV)

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*text-align: center; This is the problem*/
  font-family: 'Muli', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  color: #282828;
  background: #e5e5e5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

give duration to your fade animation. Thanks